# How to open finder inside WKWebView in macOS app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, wkwebview, finder

In macOS, our requirement is to open a Finder when clicking Upload File from a web view. It works when I opened the same URL link in Safari but inside macOS application Open Finder its not getting triggered.

I've used `WKWebKit` delegate function but its not triggered.

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView 
decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction 
decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler;
```

Also I've tried with `WKNavigationDelegate` as well but no luck.

```
webView:didStartProvisionalNavigation:
webView:didCommitNavigation:
webView:didFinishNavigation:
webView:didFailNavigation:withError:
webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:
```

And also with `WKUIDelegate` functions as well.

```
webView:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame:completionHandler:
webView:runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame:completionHandler:
webView:runJavaScriptTextInputPanelWithPrompt:defaultText:initiatedByFrame:completionHandler:
webView:createWebViewWithConfiguration:forNavigationAction:windowFeatures:
```

Here is the code I have tried,

```
@interface ViewController() <WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isFinderOpen;

@end

@implementation ViewController

(IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender {
 NSString *urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.diawi.com/"];
 [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress]]];
}

- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView runOpenPanelWithParameters:(WKOpenPanelParameters *)parameters initiatedByFrame:(WKFrameInfo *)frame completionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray<NSURL *> * _Nullable))completionHandler{
    
    if (!self.isFinderOpen) {
        self.isFinderOpen = YES;
        [self.webView.configuration.preferences setValue:@TRUE forKey:@"allowFileAccessFromFileURLs"];
        NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
        [openPanel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
        [openPanel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
            self.isFinderOpen = NO;
            if (result == NSModalResponseOK) {
                NSURL *url = [openPanel URL];
                if (url) {
                    NSLog(@"%@",url);
                }
            }
            else if (result == NSModalResponseCancel) {
                NSLog(@"nil");
            }
        }];
    }    
}
```

Any thing I'm missing in this ?

Comment: Finder is an app. Do you mean an Open panel?

Comment: Have you tried the [Displaying an upload panel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuidelegate#2138155_) section of `WKUIDelegate`?

Comment: @Willeke we have tried using upload panel as well and it didn't work. I couldn't open the panel when button is tapped inside the webview.

Comment: Post the code you tried please.

Comment: @Willeke I have edited the question and shared the code, please refer that.

Comment: Is `webView:runOpenPanelWithParameters:initiatedByFrame:completionHandler:` called? Do you set `UIDelegate`? Any exceptions?

Comment: @Willeke, no it didn't get called but i have set the UIDelegate

Comment: Post a [mre] please. How is the web view created? Where and when do you set `UIDelegate`?

Comment: @Willeke, i have shared the code in question please refer that. I have created webView in storyboard.

Comment: Is `UIDelegate` set in the storyboard? I tried your code, `runOpenPanelWithParameters` is called but there are some other issues.

Comment: you are asking about whether webView is set to UIDelegate in storyboard, right?

Comment: Yes, if you don't set `UIDelegate` in code then it must be set in the storyboard. You can check `self.webView. UIDelegate` in `buttonClick:`, is it set to the same object as `self`?

Comment: @Willeke, I have set the delegate `[self.webview setUIDelegate:self];`